# Apply transform matrix to warpTransform in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

So, I want to transform an image but can't really find a proper way to do it using OpenCV.

First thing I have image lets say 500x600px inside of which there is a distorted thing I want to "straighten up" see the image:
[image: image with distorted sudoku]

I'm obtaining the contour of the sudoku like this:

```
cropped_image, contours, _ = 
cv2.findContours(cropped_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
max_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

Then I'm getting the `max_contour` and image extreme pixels (top-left, top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left) and getting the transform matrix and transforming the image like this:

```
x, y = cropped_image.shape
image_extreme_pixels = np.array([[0, y], [x, y], [x, 0], [0, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
c_x, c_y = [], []
for i in contour:
  c_x.append(i[0][0])
  c_y.append(i[0][1])
contour_extreme_pixels = np.array([
  [min(c_x), max(c_y)],
  [max(c_x), max(c_y)],
  [max(c_x), min(c_y)],
  [min(c_x), min(c_y)]],
  dtype=np.float32)

t_matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(contour_extreme_pixels, image_extreme_pixels)

transformed_image = cv2.warpPerspective(cropped_image, t_matrix, (y, x))


plt.imshow(cropped_image, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

But when I view the image it's transformed in a weird fashion. I wanted to stretch the top parts of sudoku so that it's contour are straight.

Could you point what's wron with my code?
I'm assuming it might be the fashion in which I'm creating the 4 extreme pixels that are then put into the `getPerspectiveTransform` to get the transformation matrix but didn't manage to make it work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the extreme points I've found were incorrect.
The correct way (one of many) to find 4 extreme points in a shape that we expect to be rectangular would be something like this:

```
def get_contour_extreme_points(img, contour):
  m_point = image_center(img)
  l1, l2, l3, l4 = 0, 0, 0, 0
  p1, p2, p3, p4 = 0, 0, 0, 0

  for point in contour:
    d = distance(m_point, point[0])
    if inside_bottom_right(m_point, point[0]) and l1 < d:
      l1 = d
      p1 = point[0]
      continue
    if inside_bottom_left(m_point, point[0]) and l2 < d:
      l2 = d
      p2 = point[0]
      continue
    if inside_top_right(m_point, point[0]) and l3 < d:
      l3 = d
      p3 = point[0]
      continue
    if inside_top_left(m_point, point[0]) and l4 < d:
      l4 = d
      p4 = point[0]
      continue

  return np.float32([p1, p2, p3, p4])

def inside_bottom_right(center, point):
  return center[0] < point[0] and center[1] < point[1]

def inside_bottom_left(center, point):
  return center[0] > point[0] and center[1] < point[1]

def inside_top_right(center, point):
  return center[0] < point[0] and center[1] > point[1]

def inside_top_left(center, point):
  return center[0] > point[0] and center[1] > point[1]

def distance(p1, p2):
  return math.sqrt( ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2) )

def image_center(img):
  x, y = img.shape

  return tuple([x/2, y/2])
```

then I would have to be careful about the order of the 4 extreme points of the image. Which should look like this:

```
x, y = img.shape
img_extreme_points = np.float32([[x, y], [0, y], [x, 0], [0, 0]])
```

so first is the bottom right extreme point, then bottom left, top right and top left. As long as the extreme points index corresponds correctly the matrix will be computed correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have found out the corner points of sudoku accurately you can affine transform the input image as:

```
# Hard coded the points here assuming that you already have 4 corners of sudoku image
sudoku_corner_points = np.float32([[235, 40], [1022, 55], [190, 875], [1090, 880]])
canvas = np.ones((500, 500), dtype=np.uint8)
dst_points = np.float32([[0, 0], [500, 0], [0, 500], [500, 500]])

t_matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(sudoku_corner_points, dst_points)

transformed_image = cv2.warpPerspective(img, t_matrix, (500, 500))
```

[image]

Comment: is the order of the sudoku_corner_points and dst_points important?

Comment: Affine transform is different from perspective transform

Comment: i'm assuming that the corner points of sudoku I've found are incorrect because your code doesn't solve my issue, I'm trying to figure out what's wrong exactly